# Can repeated editing destroy an image?

Tags: photoshop-elements

I have thousands of travel shots -artistically good but I keep changing features
on Photoshop.  Presumably there is irreversible damage with each alteration.  Is
there a point reached when the damage destroys the image completely?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail of the types of changes you're making and what file formats you are using? Both will affect the answer.

Comment: Particularly, are your source images in raw or jpeg (or some other) format?

Comment: All depends on format and your workflow (e.g. tiff with layers, tiff without layers, jpeg etc), without knowing that then the answer may not fit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you do it wrong. This is actually what gave JPEG images a bad reputation. They are good for compression since they discard data each time. The algorithm is designed to remove *least* noticeable data but if you keep open a JPEG, modifying it and saving it over again and again, eventually quality will be unusable.

A software like Lightroom performs all edits non-destructively by applying them *all* on the source JPEG (or any format it supports). Each time you manipulated further, the whole history gets reprocessed on the original image. You incur degradation only once on the export, which if you choose a good quality setting is very little.

Prior to Lightroom and currently so with standard software, the trick is to work on a lossless format. You import your image and then perform all the manipulations you like but save it in something like a TIFF or PSD. When you need to further manipulate, then you open the lossly file, work some more and save it again. Only when you are ready to publish, share, post online, etc do you expect a JPEG which is compressed and perhaps reduced in resolution, so only one degradation happens which is fairly minimal. This is what is normally done by professional workflow for both stills and video.

Comment: yeah, bashing JPEG is easy. I like how you introduced nondestructive editing, so popular nowadays (even the builtin iphone software does that). and that's the point, always use the original and never overwrite it. the particular file format is not that important. even lossless format can lose data when repeatedly edited and overwritten! (think histogram stretching)

Comment: You do realize that many of us used non-destructive editing "prior to Lightroom", right? If memory serves, when Lightroom 1.0 came out, I was using Bibble 4.9.9...

Comment: Actually, I wrote the first such software at Autodesk, years before Lightoom and it was truly mind-boggling. Having no *Save* button for the first time took a while for people to trust the software.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are saving in JPEG and using anything but the top-quality compression settings. If you're using the high quality settings, this is better, but there's still loss.

That's because the image will be recompressed with each save, and the way JPEG compression works causes degradation each time until a stable state is reached — but if you make edits each time you won't reach that stable state, and anyway you probably don't want to.

As a quick test, I used ImageMagick to recompress a JPEG image over and over at 75%. The number is different from what Photoshop Elements uses, but the basic concept is the same. The samples below are uploaded as PNG files to avoid yet further recompression, and were doubled in size when I converted to PNG to make the effect more obvious. It turns out that after eight resamplings, the effect converged on a perfectly stable result, where recompressing again results in a bit-for-bit identical file.

Here's the uncompressed original:

[image: original, no jpeg compression]

Here's the result of going to 75% JPEG:

[image: first jpeg]

And here's that resaved:

[image: second pass]

You can see that just one additional pass causes quite a bit of destruction at this quality level.

So here's the final converged image (8th pass):

[image: converged jpeg]

Again, colors are definitely *even more* off, including some false color patterns, and the blocky artifacts jump out more. So, don't do that.

But here's the same thing with a 99% quality level, after 9 passes (the point where it converges so further passes are identical):

[image: 99% 9 times]

Here, the difference barely registers. (I mean that literally; compare them pixel by pixel to the non-compressed version and the deviation is just very slight random noise.) So, what if I go back to that first 75% image and then resave at 99%? Well, this, (after just once):

[image: 75% once and then 99% once]

That's definitely *visibly* better than resaving as 75% again. But, there's obvious *new* degradation around the pink trimming and the eyes. With the recycled version of the same settings, the JPEG artifacts are being exaggerated with each recompression. With the low resolution and low quality I've chosen, that turns out to be worse than recompressing everything differently.

But, it's also worth mentioning that saving 75% *one time* is much worse than resaving at 99% a *million* times. In my example case, the artifacts at 75% are so obvious that the further degradation is like dumping water in the ocean.

Of course, if you can stick to always working from uncompressed originals, you're better off.

Comment: Why is the uncompressed original so pixelated/blocky?

Comment: "and were doubled in size when I converted to PNG to make the effect more obvious" -> they're pixelated just because they're zoomed in on purpose to show pixels.